# Jest debugging in terminal error- directory missing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, automated-tests

I am beginner in Jest learning and writing testcases.
Trying to debug test file so that in terminal tried to run following command following jest document
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand
```

It give an error as per below

```
C:\Users\Documents\Jest\JestApp>node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/428f8d8b-f9f9-45f3-8961-f3cba283d0df
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
C:\Users\Documents\Jest\JestApp\node_modules\.bin\jest:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11?[39m
```

How to resolve above error and successfully debug test file in chrome for Windows.
Please post steps to debug testcase step by step.

First help me to resolve this error,
and further under test file, inside testcase added debugger; but debug mode not poping up in chrome://inspect under DevTools for node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node_modules/.bin` contains executable (binary) files. `node_modules/.bin/jest` is not valid JavaScript but shell script, this results in syntax error.

Jest entry script should be executed instead:

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand
```

Comment: still debugger is not working in chrome://inspect dedicated dev tools

Comment: node --inspect-brk node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/ab651461-dfe8-4528-8a07-484a4be5db7b
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector 
after this under test file added debugger; line and still debugging not happening. Is there any issue ?

Comment: No, that's correct. Open chrome://inspect/#devices and then proceed with debugging. The process is described at https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/ , it's not specific to Jest at this point.

Comment: @ Estus Flask,    nothing would happen to atleast prompt on screen, I wrote debugger inside test cases yet not received any prompt on node debugger window.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows machine -

```
node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js` --runInBand
```

or on other OS -

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand
```

As per documentation, https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting.
Thank you